# Stop processing large text files in Apache Spark after certain amount of errors

Tags: scala, validation, apache-spark, text-files

I'm very new to Spark. I'm working in 1.6.1.
Let's imagine I have large file, I'm reading it into RDD[String] thru textFile.
Then I want to validate each line in some function.
Because file is huge, I want to stop processing when I reached certain amount of errors, let's say 1000 lines.
Something like

`val rdd = sparkContext.textFile(fileName)
    rdd.map(line => myValidator.validate(line))`

here is validate function:

`def validate(line:String) : (String, String) = {
        // 1st in Tuple for resulted line, 2nd ,say, for validation error.
    }`

How to calculate errors inside 'validate'?. It is actually executed in parallel on multiple nodes? Broadcasts? Accumulators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior using Spark's laziness by "splitting" the result of the parsing into success and failures, calling `take(n)` on the failures, and only using the success data if there were less then `n` failures.

To achieve this more conveniently, I'd suggest changing the signature of `validate` to return some type that can easily distinguish success from failure, e.g. `scala.util.Try`:

```
def validate(line:String) : Try[String] = {
    // returns Success[String] on success, 
    // Failure (with details in the exception object) otherwise 
}
```

And then, something like:

```
val maxFailures = 1000
val rdd = sparkContext.textFile(fileName)
val parsed: RDD[Try[String]] = rdd.map(line => myValidator.validate(line)).cache()

val failures: Array[Throwable] = parsed.collect { case Failure(e) => e }.take(maxFailures)

if (failures.size == maxFailures) { 
  // report failures... 
} else {
  val success: RDD[String] = parsed.collect { case Success(s) => s }
  // continue here...
}
```

Why would this work?

- If there are less then 1000 failures, the entire dataset will be parsed when `take(maxFailures)` is called, the successful data will be cached and ready to use
- If there are 1000 failures or more, the parsing would stop there, as the `take` operation won't require anymore reads

Comment: Yep, this might work. Looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell me why on my DAG diagram I see it reads file twice?

Comment: You are right - it does appear twice, although even if I suspend execution before using the `success` RDD (meaning - after the first job was executed, but not the second), I do see that the RDD is fully cached in memory (in the UI's `Storage` section). So I don't know why it wouldn't just skip this stage. I didn't run it on a large enough file to be sure, but it seems that the second job is much faster - perhaps it doesn't really read the entire file over again... not sure.

Comment: The reason I don't want caching is that you need tweeking when using that.
I would prefer logically avoid further calculations in case of reaching maximum amount of errors.

Comment: I see. Well, can't think of an alternative, maybe someone else will, good luck